# Getting Fault 1: "SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, magento, magento-1.9

While creating a customer with Magento API using Python, i am getting this error:

```
Fault 1: "SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s), query was: SELECT `customer_entity`.* FROM `customer_entity` WHERE (entity_id ='firstname', '3876')"
```

But if i specify only the customer id, it will ask for all the other fields, and when i extend the dict with these values, the same error comes again.
Here is the dict i use to create the customer:

```
address = {}

address['customer_id'] = '3876'
address['addressdata']={}
address['addressdata']['firstname'] =  'firstname'
address['addressdata']['lastname'] = 'lastname'
address['addressdata']['city'] = 'city'
address['addressdata']['region'] = 'Texas'
address['addressdata']['region_id'] = 1
address['addressdata']['postcode'] = '23423' #ZIP
address['addressdata']['telephone'] = '3245235235' #phone
address['addressdata']['is_default_billing'] = False
address['addressdata']['is_default_shipping'] = False

address = proxy.call(session, 'customer_address.create', [address])
```

What do you think can be wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, enable sql logging (ideally only your API call should run against that server, in order to debug):

In `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql`

```
lib/varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
```

set

```
protected $_debug               = true;
protected $_logAllQueries       = true;
```

and (if nor already there) create the folder defined in

```
protected $_debugFile           = 'var/debug/sql.txt';
```

Run the API call then have a look at the log file and see what queries ran and why it gives an error.

You can also try these following links for same issue, might be helpfull for you.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/14864123
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/34997348
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/38326377